# Surpassing custom set API quota limit?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Google cloud noob here.

I've set up a custom quota (along with a default alert to email me once I hit 80% threshold of my quota) for a specific API; However, I am able to keep making requests to the API after I've gone past the quota limit I had set. I also do not receive any email alerts that I am approaching the quota.
[Image of quota being exceeded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p3uKW.png)

I'm looking for something I can do to prevent a request if I am over the quota I've set.

Haven't really found an answer after a good amount of searching. Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

I've tried changing the quota to other values, but I get the same result. Not totally sure what to try next.